# Oracle commits in for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, for-loop

I have procedure using for-loop for inserting rows from external table to a normal one. The table have about 6-7 columns. Right now I have commit on every insert, which takes about 20 minutes to insert 4mill records. Is it possible to optimize that using commit on every 1k rows or 5k using

```
if mod(i,5000)=0 then
commit;
```

and here is how the loop looks like now:

```
FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT
                    LOOP
                      begin
                              INSERT  INTO A(...)
                              values( ...);

                              commit;
                        end;
                   END LOOP;
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea.

Comment: Why not one commit at the end?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the modulo funtion:

```
for i in 1 .. arr.count loop
  begin
    insert  into a (...)
    values ( ...);

    if mod(i, 5000) = 0 then
      commit;
    end if;
  end;

  commit;
end loop;
```

However, it's often much better to read blockwise from a cursor and use `FORALL` instead. I don't know if this is possible with your external table, though.

```
declare
  type type_table_of_sometable_rows is table of sometable%rowtype;
  v_array type_table_of_sometable_rows;
  cursor mycursor is select * from sometable;
begin
  open mycursor;
  loop
    fetch mycursor bulk collect into v_array limit 5000;
    exit when v_array.count = 0;
    forall i in 1 .. v_array.count
      insert into mytable values ( v_array(i).col1, v_array(i).col2) );
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Best of all is `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT col1, col2,... FROM sometable; COMMIT;`.  But this is the best answer that actually answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
Insert into table
Select * from external_table;
Commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CURSOR xxx IS  
   SELECT 
     *
      FROM table t
      where t.id='abc';    
  for Viewxxx in xxx loop
     -- Add  logic here! 
  end loop;
```